# Flutter Firestore query with no matching results results causes query to hang when using orderBy

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query for products in a Firestore collection ordered by itemName. This all works fine and orders the documents correctly when there are documents that match the query.

The problem arises when the query has no matching document and the orderBy is used, the query never seems to complete.

This is my code:

```
CollectionReference products = Firestore.instance.collection('products');
Query query;
query = products.where('keywords', arrayContains: searchString);
query = query.orderBy('itemName', descending: false);
Stream resultsStream = query.snapshots();

StreamBuilder<Object>(
   stream: resultsStream,
   builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {

          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else {
              if (snapshot.data.documents.length > 0) {
                  return ProductList(snapshot);
              } else {
                  return Center(child: Text('No items found'));
              }
          }
```

So if the searchString is something like 'kid' and it matches results everything is fine. If the searchString is 'aaaa' and doesn't match any results. The first if statement with `!snaspshot.hasdata` is always true and the snapshot never gets data.

The weird thing is though if you remove the `query.orderBy` and get the query results that have no matching document it will get data and the `snapshot.hasData` will become `true,  it will then continue on to the next if statement and display the text 'No items found'.

I am wondering whether there is another way to check if query completed or using `!snapshot.hasData`is not suitable in this instance.

Thanks

Comment: if you enter `aaaa` then it doesnt have data, then `!snapshot.hasData` will return true, and you will have `return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());` on the screen and it will stay on the screen right?

Comment: Yes that's correct, then if I remove the filter by it does have data ( data with 0 results)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
       if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(child: Text('No items found'));
          } else {
              if (snapshot.data.documents.length > 0) {
                  return ProductList(snapshot);
              } 
          }
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
       }
```

So here first the `circularprogressindicator` will appear on the screen, after the `stream` finishes, it will enter either the if or the else according to the result.

Comment: Hi thanks for that. This unfortunately creates the reverse issue. When the query has results. It will show "no items found" instead of a loading indicator until the query finishes, then it will load the results.

Comment: Can u try and use `ConnectionState`? You can find an example here https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore

Comment: Seems to cause the exact problem I started with. Hung on connection state waiting.

Comment: Looks like it is listed as a bug https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/247